# Repeating items in ListView? its don't working fine first item display at 3rd position and repeats again from the 1st item again

Tags: android, listview, adapter, custom-adapter

Everything was working fine but now I am not getting what is happening,I have 72 items to display in the listView,its don't working fine first item display at 3rd position and other item that it repeats again from the 1st item again??

```
package com.example.kishorsinh.yogaapp.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.kishorsinh.yogaapp.Model.InstructionsData;
import com.example.kishorsinh.yogaapp.R;

import java.util.List;

public class InstructionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context applicationContext;
    List<InstructionsData> iData;

    public InstructionsAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<InstructionsData> iData) {
        this.applicationContext=applicationContext;
        this.iData=iData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return iData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return iData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.instructions_list,parent,false);
            myViewHolder=new MyViewHolder();
            myViewHolder.imageView=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inst_image);
            myViewHolder.textView1=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inst_name);
            //myViewHolder.textView2=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detail_inst);
            InstructionsData instructionsData=iData.get(position);
            myViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(instructionsData.getImage_inst());
            myViewHolder.textView1.setText(instructionsData.getInstructionslist());
            //myViewHolder.textView2.setText(instructionsData.getInstructionslist());
            convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            myViewHolder=(MyViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView1;
        //TextView textView2;
    }

}
```

it just repeat all name of list you can see in image below...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MkM6.jpg

Comment: just remove this `if(convertView==null)`

Comment: please mark answer as accepted if working fine

Comment: My suggestion:you should keep your logic that reuse view for more smoothly scrolling and change your getView logic do what I post in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say

> its don't working fine first item display at 3rd position and other item that it repeats again from the 1st item again

you need to bind data without any condition for each item like you are only binding data when `converconvertView == null`

so just remove this

`if(convertView==null)`

condition and always bind data without any condition

Answer (score 0):

Your getView method logic is error ,appearance of repeat item was caused by reuse of view,change your getView method like follow code snippet.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.instructions_list,parent,false);
       myViewHolder=new MyViewHolder();
       myViewHolder.imageView=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inst_image);
       myViewHolder.textView1=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inst_name);
       //myViewHolder.textView2=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detail_inst);
       convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);
    }
    else{
        myViewHolder=(MyViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    InstructionsData instructionsData=iData.get(position);
    myViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(instructionsData.getImage_inst());
    myViewHolder.textView1.setText(instructionsData.getInstructionslist());
    //myViewHolder.textView2.setText(instructionsData.getInstructionslist());
    return convertView;
 }
```